# Hook for tab completion in emacs (interactive) file input?

Tags: emacs, elisp, symlink

In emacs, the following will define a function that, when called interactively, will ask the user for a filename:

```
(defun do-something (filename )
  (interactive "FFilename: ")
  ...
  )
```

When the user is entering a filename, they can use tab-completion, etc.  Does anyone know if there are any hooks in that file-entry code?  In particular, I would like to modify my find-file command so that windows symlinks (which show up as "foo.lnk") are automatically followed to their target if you hit tab.

I'm currently using [w32-symlinks](http://centaur.maths.qmul.ac.uk/Emacs/files/w32-symlinks.el), which means that at least if I hit enter on the link, then it will open up the target in diredit.  But I'd prefer to be able to just tab-complete through it to the file I'm looking at, rather than opening diredit and then doing a second find-file command.

Answer (score 2):

Before reinventing the wheel, perhaps put (ido-mode t) in your .emacs file and see if it does what you are wanting.

I dont use windows, but I use ido and it is much nicer than default.

Comment: Interesting mode; I'll have to play with it.  Unfortunately, after playing with it for a while, it does not appear to me to solve the problem in question -- i.e., it doesn't understand windows syminks.

Comment: Actually, it may be possible to do something with Ido-Make-Dir-List-Hook or Ido-Make-File_List-Hook.  I'll let you know if I get anything working.

Answer (score 1):

The answer to your question in general is to use `completing-read` directly in the `interactive` spec -- don't use a string argument. IOW, compose your own set of completions.

Or you can bind `read-file-name-function` to your own function which performs file-name completion (and, e.g., incorporates the standard behavior). See standard library `minibuffer.el`.